# How to set labels above the input with @media?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have simple Bootstrap block which looks like this:

[image]

The main problem occurs on smaller resolution, like 1280*600:

[image]

As you can see the mos of the ip is not seen, so I want to set labes above the inputs like this:

[image]

```
<div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput" style="text-align:center">Server IP</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter IP Address" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="textinput">Port</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Port" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean 600x1280 rather than the other way round as 1280x600 is quite wide.

How about something like this..

```
<div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-7">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput" style="text-align:center">Server IP</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter IP Address" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">Port</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Port" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```